# get perticular value From json in Mule Logger

Tags: json, mule, mule-studio

Below is my Json

```
{"caseType":"CashLess","claimNo":9.0}
```

how to get **caseType** value in logger.
below my config XML

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
<logger message="#['\n JSON::\n'+ message.payload.caseType+'\n']" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

but it is giving error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to add **returnClass="java.util.HashMap"** in *json:json-to-object-transformer*

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to Object" returnClass="java.util.HashMap"/>
```